# php if en modal de bootstrap 4

Tags: php, bootstrap, php7

algo me tiene confundido .. tengo una modal que muestra un botón ... esta relacionado en el id de una publicación .. la modal si me trae el id porq las acciones de eliminar modificar y publicar funcionan bien.. pero al momento de colocar un if dentro de la modal no funciona ... la idea es q si el id es 0 no muestre .. si es 1 muestre ..

```html
<?php    if($row['estatus'] == '0'){?>

              <button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id'];?>" class="btn btn-outline-info changeServicio" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".MostrarS" name="mostrar">no mostrar</button>


<?php }else{ ?>

<button type="button" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id'];?>" class="btn btn-outline-info changeServicio" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".MostrarS" name="publicado">Mostrar</button>


<?php } ?>
```

cuando coloco el cod fuera de la modal funciona perfectamente pero dentro de la modal no .. porq pasa esto ?

```html
<a href="" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#exampleModal" id="<?php echo $row['servicio_id']; ?>" class=" material-icons detalles"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> settings
```

Comment: has probado usando echo al boton? 
es decir, sin cerrar la "?>" dentro del if

if (condicion= 1){ echo boton;}

Comment: disculpame pero no entendi

Comment: cuando tratas de imprimir el row con "echo"

puedes hacerlo todo , incluso la impresion del boton con exho si se cumple la condicion

Comment: pero la condicion se cumple sin problema (fuera de la modal ) presenta problema es dentro de la modal

Comment: En el `data-target=".MostrarS"` debes de colocar el id que tiene asignado tu modal ejemplo: `data-target="#exampleModal"`

Comment: si ya salio el estilo pero el if sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: @Ragnarok La condición la estas colocando al abrir el modal?

Comment: ya se soluciono mil gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

para poder mostrar información usando condicionales con php puedes usar echo
asi como lo usas para traerte el resultado de tu consulta sql

## explicacion

si (condicicion = true){
echo 'contenido a mostrar 1';
}sinosecumple{
echo 'contenido a mostrar 2';
}

## ejemplo

```
 <?php
if($row['estatus'] == '0'){

echo '<button type=\"button\" id='.$row['servicio_id'].' class=\"btn btn-outline-info changeServicio\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\".MostrarS\" name=\"mostrar\">no mostrar</button>
    ';
    
     }else{
    
    echo '<button type=\"button\" id='.$row['servicio_id'].' class=\"btn btn-outline-info changeServicio\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\".MostrarS\" name=\"publicado\">Mostrar</button>
    ';
    
     } ?>
```

Comment: colocandolo asi no me realiza la funcion y el stilo de bootstrap se pierde

Comment: edite la respuesta para que funcionen los estilos, prueba y me dices

Comment: no en la modal sigue sin el estilo bootstrap y sin cumplir la funcion